# How to reproduce Application Not Responding (ANR) from Activity and from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog

I need to reproduce Application Not Responding (ANR) dialogs from Activity and from BroadCastReceiver.
I tried to create a simple button click:

```
 public void makeANRClick(View view){
    while (true);
}
```

With this code I reproduced ANR on emulator with android 2.3.7. Same code doesn't work on real device with the newest android versions (4+).

Another attempt was as follows:

```
public void onMakeANRClick(View view){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(15000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This doesn't help also.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Did the code from second attempt work on Android 2.3.7?

Comment: Yes, it works. But I need options for the newest Android versions (4 an greater).

Comment: Thanks for the point. I'll take a look at strict mode. But currently I prefer some not test way.

Answer (score 1):

Keyword **multi threading**. Please read this topic http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html 
Also there is no way to manage UI components at Broadcast Reciever, Because it is no UI component.
Also there is option in Development Options called "Show All ANR"

Comment: I want to reproduce ANR and not to avoid.

Comment: There is two options in this document. at the title: What Triggers ANR?

Comment: 1) No response to an input event (such as key press or screen touch events) within 5 seconds.
2) A BroadcastReceiver hasn't finished executing within 10 seconds.

Comment: you could also cleaned your redundant code by proguard or on some pre-compilation stage

Comment: As I see on device button remain pressed. UI thread was stuck but ANR not appear.

Comment: @AlexanderMyznikov Did you solve this problem? I also need to reproduce ANR trigger

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [StrictMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html).  And this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oGrXdxpWgyY), too.

"StrictMode is a developer tool which detects things you might be doing by accident and brings them to your attention so you can fix them. "

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't help me with reproducing ANR dialogs.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can check the dump state to check info about your process
https://source.android.com/devices/input/diagnostics.html

I reproduce your code  and then pull the 'dumpstate_app_anr.txt.gz'
and this was the result

PID   TID PR CPU% S     VSS     RSS PCY UID      Thread          Proc

15287 15287  0  83% R 227152K  25152K  fg u0_a135  a.stackoverflow mx.syca.stackoverflow

07-03 08:46:12.454  1618  1636 I ActivityManager: Killing proc 12946:mx.syca.stackoverflow/u0a135: force stop

It took about 2 minutes to get the ANR dialog

Hope it helps

Comment: About 2 minutes to get ANR. It's weird and not acceptable. In Android docs lines about 5 seconds for activity and 10 seconds for BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: @AlexanderMyznikov i know its weird but i saw it in my phone, test how much will take on yours , let me see if i can find in the file the time in which the app started

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that the best way to perform ANR in java (dalvik) is to perform absurd ammount of calculations, including function calls.

Perhaps something akin to:

```
Integer useless = 0;
for (i=2147483648;i<2147483647;i++){
  useless = Math.random() * Math.random() * Math.random() * Math.random();
}
```

This will at least, trigger some delay, and ANR on weaker systems.